# PHP: How to generate a <ul><li> tree in an xml2assoc array result?

Tags: php, tree

I have seen many PHP function on how to generate a `<ul><li>` tag but my array input is quite complicated I guess. It is an array returned from a custom function called [xml2assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php#88264)

My question is how can I convert the returned xml2assoc array result to a `<ul><li>` formatted HTML code using PHP.

Thanks.

```
$tree = array(
    0 => array(
        'tag' => 'NavigationMode',
        'value' => array(
            0 => array(
                'tag' => 'Title',
                'value' => 'Introduction'
            ),
            1 => array(
                'tag' => 'NavigationNode',
                'value' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'tag' => 'Title',
                        'value' => 'Sub Intro'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'tag' => 'NavigationMode',
        'value' => array(
            0 => array(
                'tag' => 'Title',
                'value' => 'Module 1'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The final output that I need to generate is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    Introduction
    <ul>
        <li>Sub Intro</li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Module 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The xml is not in an altogether friendly format for recursion. Have you tried simplexml (http://www.php.net/simplexml)?

Comment: @mladen: xml got nothing's to do with his problem. he already got the nice arrayed $tree data struct

Comment: @mladen: My former boss told me that simplexml can't handle xml files larger than 2 MB so I have used xml2assoc. I'm having a hard time solving my problem :(

Comment: "but my array input is quite complicated I guess" - no, it isn't. could be easier, but it's not that bad.

Comment: @marknt15: +1 since the question is in a lot better a shape than most first time questions.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks Sir Tomalak. From now on I will help this wonderful community to the best that I can :) . About my question, it is because I am generating a dynamic tree menu using jquery and the parameter is an array result from the custom xml2assoc array.

Comment: @marknt15: I gathered that. :) But *instead* of using xml2assoc in the first place, you could simply use a stylesheet on the XML and have it transformed in under 10 lines of PHP. Okay... You might need to look into learning XSLT, but if you work with XML regularly, this might be a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ok, I am not yet familiar with XSLT so I pursued on doing the xml2assoc way due to deadline. Thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't test it for variations of the demo data ...

```
<?php

function getTitle($node) {
    foreach ($node['value'] as $cnode) {
            if ($cnode['tag'] == 'Title') {
                return $cnode['value'];
            }
    }

    return 'untitled';
}

function getCNodes($node) {
    $cnodes = array();

    foreach ($node['value'] as $cnode) {
        if ($cnode['tag'] == 'NavigationNode') {
            $cnodes[] = $cnode;
        }
    }

    return $cnodes;
}

function runTree($node) {
    $title  = getTitle($node);
    $cnodes = getCNodes($node);

    if (count($cnodes) > 0) {
        $out = '<li>' . $title . "\n" . '<ul>';
        foreach ($cnodes as $cnode) {
            $out .= runTree($cnode);
        }
        $out .= '</ul>' . "\n" . '</li>' . "\n";

        return $out;
    } else {
        return '<li>' . $title . '</li>' . "\n";
    }
}


$tree = array(
    0 => array(
        'tag' => 'NavigationMode',
        'value' => array(
                0 => array(
                        'tag' => 'Title',
                        'value' => 'Introduction'
                ),
                1 => array(
                        'tag' => 'NavigationNode',
                        'value' => array(
                                0 => array(
                                        'tag' => 'Title',
                                        'value' => 'Sub Intro'
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'tag' => 'NavigationMode',
        'value' => array(
                0 => array(
                        'tag' => 'Title',
                        'value' => 'Module 1'
                )
        )
    )
);



echo '<ul>';
foreach ($tree as $node) {
    echo runTree($node);
}
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have XML as input, why not use XSLT to transform it to `<ul>`?

I guess your input looks something like this (I assume "Navigation*M*ode" is a typo):

```
<tree>
  <NavigationNode>
    <title>Introduction</title>
    <NavigationNode>
      <title>Sub Intro</title>
    </NavigationNode>
  </NavigationNode>
  <NavigationNode>
    <title>Module 1</title>
  </NavigationNode>
</tree>
```

With a small XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/tree">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="NavigationNode" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NavigationNode">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="title" />
      <xsl:if test="NavigationNode">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="NavigationNode" />
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This output is produced:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Introduction
    <ul>
      <li>Sub Intro</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Module 1</li>
</ul>
```

[The PHP documentation shows how to use XSLT.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples.php) It's simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick PHP implementation for your array structure to get you started:

```
function create_html_list($nodes)
{
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $childNodes = $node['value'];
        $titleNode = array_shift($childNodes);

        echo "<li>", $titleNode['value'];

        if (count($childNodes) > 0) {
            create_html_list($childNodes);
        }

        echo "</li>";
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```