# Symfony: recursive call in template

Tags: php, symfony1

I need to render a nested set tree as a li-structure with unlimited depth. While I understand how to do it in plain php (like here: [PHP: How to generate a <ul><li> tree in an xml2assoc array result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784762/php-how-to-generate-a-ulli-tree-in-an-xml2assoc-array-result/784816#784816)), I hate echoing html tags and would like to have it done in a template. Is it possible with PHP as a templating language? Where should I define a recursive function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, I depends on how much 'code' is needed in each iteration.

For simple trees, I would just declare a function at the top of the view-file. (Since I think that function has only real value in that separate file).

For trees with a bit more rendering, I would create a separate partial file. That file could be called in the view file and in the partial file itself.

You could also create a helper file, which you use on that specific page, put than the partial would make more sense and is easier to implement (and you can use all other helper functions and symfony functions)

Comment: Hey, thanks. How about performance helper vs partial in this case?

Comment: I think helpers could be a bit faster since they are accessible once loaded. The partials are loaded recursively, so everytime it will have to go through the Symfony view stack. But you could cache partials as well, and partials have a much cleaner code. (More readable for the user), and is more pure in a MVC perspective.

Answer (score 0):

hm, here is my sollution:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $records
 * @var $field
 */
?>

<?php if( isset($records) && is_object($records) && count($records) > 0 ): ?>
  <div id="document-nested-set">
    <ul class="nested_set_list">
    <?php $prevLevel = 0; $is_first = true; ?>
    <?php foreach($records as $record): ?>
      <?php if($prevLevel > 0 && $record['level'] == $prevLevel)  echo '</li>';
      if($record['level'] > $prevLevel)  echo '<ul>';
      elseif ($record['level'] < $prevLevel) echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $prevLevel - $record['level']); ?>
      <?php $rel = $record['lft']=='1'?'root':($record['is_approved'] && $record['is_checked']?'document':'document_grey') ?>
      <li id ="phtml_<?php echo $record->id ?>"  rel="<?php echo $rel ?>" <?php echo $is_first?'class="open"':'' ?>>
          <a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins><?php echo $record->$field;?></a>
      <?php $prevLevel = $record['level']; $is_first = false; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Note that if your php version is 5.3 then you can make Lambda Function to render your tree.

Comment: could you give an example of doing it with lamdba in a separate answer? This approach looks really promising.

Answer (score 0):

an easy example:

```
<?php
    $input = array('c' => array('c1' => 't1', 'c2' => array('c21' => array('c211' => 't2'), 'c22' => 't3')));

    $iterate = function($array) use (&$iterate) {
        $out = '<ul>';
        foreach($array as $key => $child)
            $out .= '<li>'.$key.': '.( is_array($child) ? $iterate($child) : $child ).'</li>';
        return $out.'</ul>';
    }
?>

<html><body><?php echo $iterate($input); ?></body></html>
```